# GLSL: Using Depth

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I've a problem with depth and the GLSL-Shader. If I use the for z: in_Position.z - 1, the half of the texture is cutted out. You can see it on the following image:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I use depth with shaders?

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
in vec2 in_TextureCoord;

out vec4 pass_Color;
out vec2 pass_TextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4 (in_Position.x, in_Position.y, in_Position.z - 1, 1);

    pass_Color = in_Color;
    pass_TextureCoord = in_TextureCoord;
}
```

Comment: Screenshot link broken?

Comment: For me, the screenshot link works :O. Here's an alternative link: http://s7.directupload.net/images/140206/wvpkc3qg.png

Comment: Screenshot link is forbidden for me.

Comment: Have edited to embed with i.stack.imgur

Comment: Now, here the imgur URL: http://imgur.com/ZFCWuLj

Comment: What does depth have to do with anything in this question? All I see is a triangle that is probably supposed to be a quad. If you have 4 points and they do not all exist in the same plane then `GL_QUAD` will often only draw 1 triangle.

Comment: What are the input positions for the vertices. What type of primitves are you drawing? Please add the actual geometry data which you are sending to the shader.